# Tablet: on orientationchange the page jumps to start

Tags: javascript, html, tablet

I have a problem with Samsung tablet, if the user is at the bottom of the page and changes orientation, it jumps again to the start of the page.

I am not using any event listener like "orientationchange" etc

In Ipad the user remians on same position on changing the orientation.

any help.

Comment: check another browser on your samsung, also another android tablet, I think this behavior should be triggered by the samsung browser only not all android tablets

Answer (score 0):

In order to grab control of the orientation-change, you can use something like this:

```
let View = // object
{
    onTilt: function()
    {
        // get target scroll-height and do some stuff
    }
};


window.addEventListener
(
    "resize", function()
    {
        var x, y, d, a, t;

        x = window.innerWidth,
        y = window.innerHeight,
        d = Math.gcd(x,y);
        a = {x:(x / d), y:(y / d)};

        vSys.Size = // object
        {
            x:window.screen.availWidth,
            y:window.screen.availHeight
        };

        t = ((y > x) ? 'high' : 'wide');

        if ((vSys.tilt != t) ? true : false)
        { View.onTilt(t) }

        View.tilt = t;
    },
    false
);


Math.gcd = function(a,b)
{
    var t, m;

    if (b > a)
    {
        t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t
    }

    while (b != 0)
    {
        m = a%b;
        a = b;
        b = m;
    }

    return a;
};
```